# Custom field deserialization in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have been looking for something like this for a while, but can't seem to gather enough information on how to go about it.

I am basically looking for something similar to a callback that happens every time a field is deserialized. In our case, we would use that callback to modify the actual value assigned to the object depending on certain flag (a different attribute) existing on the original byte stream.

For example, imagine we want to clear certain value from our local object that lives in a cache. We can't set it to null in order to clear it, because when we deserialize it, the field will not be sent down. We could send down a list of field numbers to be cleared instead, and on deserialization check if the current field number being parsed is inside our set of clear fields.

What is the best way to go about modifying how deserialization works or, at least, be able to hook in right before or after it happens? (i.e, have a custom "hasfield" logic).

I am aware of [OnDeserializedAttribute] and [OnDeserializingAttribute], but those methods are called back with just a context in them, and only one time per object.

Thank you for your help in advance.

**Possible Solution**

Finally found some light in the subject, after digging a bit through the source.
The downside is that , as far as I know, if you use this solution you will not be able to use the [ProtoMember] tags in your classes.
This is also a v2 only solution (I believe).

If we compile our serializer on runtime, we can use the "SetSpecified" method for each field we need. This way, we can assign instance methods to be called whenever a given field is set (during deserialization) or retrieved (during serialization). I am curious to know if there is an attribute to assign these methods.

Here is what we did:

```
static protected void InitSerializer(Type type) {
    RuntimeTypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
    MetaType metaType = model.Add(type, true);

    ValueMember nameField = metaType.AddField(1, "name");

    MethodInfo setSpecified = type.GetMethod("SetNameSpecified", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    MethodInfo getSpecified = type.GetMethod("GetNameSpecified", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    nameField.SetSpecified(getSpecified, setSpecified);
}

#region Serialization Callbacks
protected bool GetNameSpecified() {
    Debug.Log ("Get Name Specified");

    bool isNameSpecified = false;

    // Your logic here
    return isNameSpecified;
}

protected void SetNameSpecified(bool specified) {
    Debug.Log ("Set Name Specified");
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I am confused how a value being assigned to a property might not exist in the stream?

Comment: I have edited my question to better show an example of what we want to do. You are right that it was confusing. Thank you for your clarification.